# dialogApi callback is not executing in iPad for Word

Tags: office-js

This may be a regression with the latest version of word for iPad.

```
Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify(msg));
```

This is no longer executing on word 2.0.3 (170426).

Also events are not calling back either.  For testing purposes I modified my processEvent method to display the error code and that method is not getting called either.  Works fine on all other platforms.

This same code previously worked on iPad prior to the most recent release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now working again in version 2.1 (170512).  So looks like it was a regression issue with that particular version of word for the iPad.